# Having a relation 1 to many on Doctrine but having 2 fields being the primary key on the other end

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml, dql

Does anyone knows how can I have a relation 1 to many in doctrine but in this special way:

in my principal table I have some fields, almnost none of them are fields which could have translations

```
Table1:
table_id <- primary key
numeric_field1
numeric_field1
numeric_field3
```

now in my Table1_translations I have all the fields which could be translated

```
Table2:
table_id <- primary key along with language
language <- this contains 2 letters representing which language is being stored in this row
string_field1
string_field2
string_field3
```

I've got a simple idea on how to represent this with YAML, but my question would be, how can I retrieve this data?

```
Table1:
table_id numeric_field1 numeric_field2 numeric_field3
 1             123           321            415

Table2
table_id language string_field1 string_field2 string_field3
 1         en        hello         happy         world
 1         es        hola          feliz         mundo
```

So, for row with table_id=1 I have 2 rows in table2 which correspond to the strings each in a different language (en & es) with this im trying to manage some sort of localization but on the database since these could be texts

thanks in advance :)

Comment: More details please, is there a correspondence between numeric field1 and string row1? Why do you call it 'row' 1? Example data perhaps?

Comment: I'm confused as well. Can you state what are you are trying to do (have a table with translations maybe?), then how are you trying to do it, but don't interweave both.

Comment: How is your description related to the title? You now how represent it, how about letting us know how you represent is so that we can help you?

Comment: Sorry about calling em rows, they are really fields. I have added the sample data to the original post

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to add a where clause specifying which language you want based on localization. So if you, in the application or the database, store a language variable for the user, then you simply add a where clause refernceing this variable or joining to the user table to get the local language that person needs (altough I'd suggest grabbing this value once on login and keeping it avialble thorugh the whole session).